# How to replace a sentence in line of string address?

Tags: python

I need help replacing a part of string on a list of file's address location.

The file address looks like this :

```
/SfSNet/Images_mask/10_face.png
```

and I need to change it into something like this

```
/SfSNet/Images_mask/10_mask.png
```

I know it is possible to count the index since the front string are the same but it will be annoying in case I want to run the code on other PC. I read something about regex but it isn't clear for me. So maybe if someone can help me with this or have any other solution will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: So would it be the same for all cases? Same structure?

Comment: yes, the only difference would be only the number lets say 1_face,2_face,etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the structure of all file names is as the above, you could use `re.sub` as:

```
s = '/SfSNet/Images_mask/10_face.png'

s.replace('_face.png', '_mask.png')
# '/SfSNet/Images_mask/10_mask.png'
```

Comment: Am I missing an obvious reason why you can't just use str.replace?

Comment: Yes that was definitely going the complicated way thanks for pointing out @tomjn

Comment: @yatu Just `s.replace('face', 'mask')` will do in this case :)

Comment: Well @tomjn I'd add some boundaries there just in case, otherwise it could match substrings containing ' face'  too

Comment: I already tried both and both works perfectly and replace is easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

If a simple `str.replace` lacks generality<sup>1</sup>, consider doing operations like this is with `os.path`.

```
>>> import os.path   
>>>
>>> s = '/SfSNet/Images_mask/10_face.png'                                             
>>> folder, file = os.path.split(s) # ('/SfSNet/Images_mask', '10_face.png')                                          
>>> name, ext = os.path.splitext(file) # ('10_face', '.png')                                         
>>> new_name = '{}_{}{}'.format(name.rsplit('_', 1)[0], 'mask', ext)            
>>> os.path.join(folder, new_name)                                              
'/SfSNet/Images_mask/10_mask.png'
```

<sup>1</sup> For example, if you want to preserve the extension name without hardcoding it or if the substring you want to replace might appear in the directory name itself.